# Keep scroll visible but disable when nav menu open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav menu working but the page is still scrollable when that becomes visible over the top of the rest of the content. Because the button is positioned so it's in the same place the page would jump about too much if the scroll bar was hidden. I want to disable the scrollbar on the body when the active class is active. I had tried using CSS `position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll` on body but this adds double scrolling and doesn't always revert.

I'm hoping the JS can be modified to keep the scrollbar present but not scrollable while the nav is open I'm just not sure how to approach this in a workable way.

```js
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.nav-action');
const siteNav = document.querySelector('.site-nav');

function onClick(event) {
  siteNav.classList.toggle('active');
}

navButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

```css
.site-header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 10px #000000;
}

.site-header-fill {
    height: 80px;
}

.site-logo-container {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.site-logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

.site-nav-action-container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.site-nav {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3399ff;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

.site-nav.active {
    display: block;
}

.site-nav-content {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-nav-content {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
}

.site-nav-pages {
    text-align:center;
}

.nav-action {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.pagefill {
  display: block;
  with: 50%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="site-header ">
   <div class="site-logo-container">
      <img class="site-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>☰</p>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="site-nav">
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>×</p>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-content">
      <div class="site-nav-pages">
         <p>Page 1</p>
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <p>Page 3</p>
         <p>Page 4</p>
         <p>Page 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


   <div class="pagefill"></div>
```

`EDIT`

Adding this seems to do the trick but the issue is removing the active class when the nav is closed. The position and overflow-y elements also need to be in the main body class too but this is close.

```
body.active, html{
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When **site-nav** has a class **'active'** I added **position of fixed** to body in order to avoid scrolling when **nav** is enabled

```js
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.nav-action');
const siteNav = document.querySelector('.site-nav');

function onClick(event) {
  siteNav.classList.toggle('active');
  if(siteNav.classList.contains('active')){
    document.body.style.position = 'fixed'
  }else{
    document.body.style.position = 'static'
  }
}

navButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

```css
.site-header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 10px #000000;
}

.site-header-fill {
    height: 80px;
}

.site-logo-container {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.site-logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

.site-nav-action-container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.site-nav {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3399ff;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

.site-nav.active {
    display: block;
}

.site-nav-content {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-nav-content {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
}

.site-nav-pages {
    text-align:center;
}

.nav-action {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.pagefill {
  display: block;
  with: 50%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="site-header ">
   <div class="site-logo-container">
      <img class="site-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>☰</p>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="site-nav">
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>×</p>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-content">
      <div class="site-nav-pages">
         <p>Page 1</p>
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <p>Page 3</p>
         <p>Page 4</p>
         <p>Page 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


   <div class="pagefill"></div>
```

Comment: +1 New knowledge for me, i thought applying `overflow-y: none` to `body` is the only way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of shift. I mentioned in my question I'd tried that. I specifically need the scroll bar to remain visible but be disabled when the class is active so that the button remains in position.

Answer (score 1):

So, Here's what you need. I solved your problem, by using `window.scroll()` and `onscroll` event listener on **window**, I am just checking if **siteNav** has active class, if so then I added and an eventListener to **window**, if it is scrolled, I'm keeping the scroll at top, by `window.scroll(0,0)`.

```js
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.nav-action');
const siteNav = document.querySelector('.site-nav');
function disableScroll () {
  window.scroll(0,0)
}

function onClick(event) {
  siteNav.classList.toggle('active');
  if(siteNav.classList.contains('active')){
      document.body.classList.add('active')
      window.addEventListener('scroll', disableScroll)
  } else{
    document.body.classList.remove('active')
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',disableScroll)
  }
}

navButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', onClick));
```

```css
   
  body.active::-webkit-scrollbar{
    background:rgba(150,150,150,.2);
  }
.site-header {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 10px #000000;
}

.site-header-fill {
    height: 80px;
}

.site-logo-container {
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.site-logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}

.site-nav-action-container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.site-nav {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3399ff;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}

.site-nav.active {
    display: block;
}

.site-nav-content {
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-nav-content {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
}

.site-nav-pages {
    text-align:center;
}

.nav-action {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.pagefill {
  display: block;
  with: 50%;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="site-header ">
   <div class="site-logo-container">
      <img class="site-logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>☰</p>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="site-nav">
   <div class="site-nav-action-container">
      <button class="nav-action">
         <p>×</p>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="site-nav-content">
      <div class="site-nav-pages">
         <p>Page 1</p>
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <p>Page 3</p>
         <p>Page 4</p>
         <p>Page 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


   <div class="pagefill"></div>
```

Comment: Yours is the closest answer so far. I was close to solving in my question. I just need to append an active class to body when it's open because with your answer the scrollbar is still visible which is confusing. `body.active, html{
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}` needs to be added, this keeps the scrollbar as a whole but not the actual scroll handle.

Comment: I have edited the answer does that answer your question?

Comment: Very close. I want the arrows retained as in the testing I've done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want but I hope it is:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Salarr96/pen/ZEKzZEp)

I changed JS like this:

```
   var pf = document.body.querySelector('.pagefill'); // added
   function onClick(event) {
   siteNav.classList.toggle('active');
   siteNav.style.overflowY = "scroll"; // added
   pf.classList.toggle('pf-height'); // added
 }
```

and created this new class for the div with .pagefill class:

```
  .pf-height {
      height: 0;
  }
```

with this change if you open the nav it will have scrollbar but with no scrollable feature

Comment: Hey, that's pretty close but the pagefill was just to give an example of the scrolling so the scrollbar was there. I'd rather add an active class to the body which does work but I need alternatives set on the body so it still scrolls without.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript will prevent the page width from jumping around when the scrollbar is hidden. Works great in any browser, regardless of its scrollbar width.

```
function toggleMenu() {
   // get width before hiding scrollbar
   let oldWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // toggle CSS class that sets overflow to hidden
   document.body.classList.toggle('MenuOpen');

   // get new width after hiding scrollbar
   let newWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

   // set margin-right value equal to width of the scrollbar
   let scrollbarWidth = Math.max(0, newWidth - oldWidth);
   document.body.style.marginRight = `${scrollbarWidth}px`;
}
```

...and some CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: #e6e6e6; /* color of fake scrollbar */
}

body.MenuOpen {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make the page unscrollable you just need to change the property `overflow` to `hidden` by :

```
body{
    overflow: hidden; // to prevent scrolling
}
```